# Kinect-WPF Focus on Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, apple-tv

I am wondering if it is possible to implement an interface similar to Apple's tvOS in WPF with Kinect v2 whereby the hovering of a hand on the screen would focus on the closest button in a grid layout filled with buttons as illustrated in the link below:

https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/images/overview-clear.mp4

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvKOzo `Mockup illustrating intended interface`

If it is possible to implement such an interface, can somebody provide any guidelines, pseudocode or libraries that can help achieve such an interface using WPF and Kinect v2.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transform your Skeleton space to a 2d space (color space for instance) and map that space to your WPF view, you'll then have a stream of x and y coordinates of your hand.

Then you can do a AABB collision detection to determine if your hand "touches" the button.

There's some Kinect example projects on:

http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/

Controls-Basic-WPF seems like a good starting point.